# ¿Que significa el siguiente error? de .NET a MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Estoy realizando la siguiente sintaxis al la base de datos para guardar:

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; port=3306; database=creawood;Uid=root;pwd='';");
            conectar.Open();

            MySqlCommand ciudad = new MySqlCommand("Select idCiudad, departamento from ciudad where nombre_ciudad='"+cbCiudad.SelectedItem+"'",conectar);
            MySqlDataReader idciudad = ciudad.ExecuteReader();

            string idciud="";
            string depa="";
            if (idciudad.Read())
            {
                 idciud = idciudad.GetValue(0).ToString();
                 depa = idciudad.GetValue(1).ToString();
            }
            int rol = 1 + cbRol.SelectedIndex;
            conectar.Close();
            conectar.Open();
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Now;
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(string.Format("Insert into usuario (idUsuario,Rol_idRol,tipo_doc,nro_doc,nombre,apellido,correo,contraseña,direccion," +
                "Ciudad_idCiudad,   Departamento_idDepartamento,telefono,genero,fecha_creacion,fecha_actualizacion) " +
                "VALUES("+txtID+",'"+rol+"" +
                ",'"+cbTipoDoc.SelectedItem + ",'"+txtNroDoc.Text+",'"+txtNombre.Text+",'"+txtApellido.Text+",'"+txtCorreo.Text+",'"
                   +txtpassword.Text+",'"+txtDireccion.Text+",'"+idciud+",'"+depa+",'"+txtTelefono.Text+",'"+cbGenero.SelectedItem + ",'"+fecha+ "'"), conectar);


            MySqlDataReader leer = comando.ExecuteReader();

            if (leer.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar");
            }
            conectar.Close();
        }
```

Pero al momento de guardar sale el siguiente mensaje:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.TextBox, Text:
>   2,'1,'CC,'123456789,'Alexis,'Gallo,'Agallo,'123456,'calle,'5,'6,' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no usas parametros, concatener los valores en un string es una pesima practica

```
string query =  "Select idCiudad, departamento from ciudad where nombre_ciudad= ?ciuidad"

MySqlCommand ciudad = new MySqlCommand(,conectar);
ciudad.Parameters.AddWithValue("?ciuidad", cbCiudad.SelectedValue);

MySqlDataReader reader = ciudad.ExecuteReader();

string idciud="";
string depa="";
if (idciudad.Read())
{
     idciud = reader["idCiudad"].ToString();
     depa = reader["departamento"].ToString();
}
```

Y luego usar para el insert

```
string insert = @"Insert into usuario (idUsuario,Rol_idRol,tipo_doc,nro_doc,nombre,apellido,correo,contraseña,direccion,
                    Ciudad_idCiudad, Departamento_idDepartamento,telefono,genero,fecha_creacion,fecha_actualizacion) 
                    VALUES(?idUsuario,?rol,?tipo_doc, ....)";

MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(insert, conectar);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?idUsuario", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?rol", rol);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?tipo_doc", cbTipoDoc.SelectedValue);
//resto parametros

int rowaffected = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (rowaffected > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Datos guardados");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar");
}
```

Siempre debes usar parametros respectando los tipos de datos

- Si en los combos usas el `DataSource`, entonces al asignar el `ValueMember` podrias usar el `SelectedValue` para tomar la seleccion
- Usa el `ExecuteNonQuery()` para ejecutar el insert, el reader solo aplica en los select
- Si el campo de la tabla es numerico recuerda convertirlo con el `Convert.ToInt32()` asi sabras que asignas el tipo de dato correcto

Answer (score 2):

`VALUES("+txtID+`   te faltó llamar la propiedad `Text`

`txtID.Text`